# Windows Phone Emulator with VS 2013 is still loading

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, emulation

I have Windows 8.1 Pro 64bit and Visual Studio 2013.
The problem is, when i start debugging with WVGA 512MB for example, it says that the operating system is starting, but it never finish loading.

I disabled my firewall (before this i got always error code 32775).
In BIOS i enabled Hardware Virtualization and in Windows Hyper V is enabled,
but i could'nt found other entries in BIOS like EPT, VMX, XD.
I run windows tool coreinfo.exe and it says:

HYPERVISOR * Hypervisor is present
VMX        - Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
EPT        - Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT)

Comment: when i run coreinfo.exe with disabled VT in BIOS, it says that both EPT and SLAT is enabled (*) and HYPERVISOR is disabled (-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try disabling any AntiVirus Software you had installed in your PC
2. Try to make sure you have the admin rights to use Virtualization.

Comment: disabled avast! and windows firewall.

Comment: but nothing happens. emulator is still loading